# releasing memory from char array

Tags: c++

Getting the sound of an error (or may be exception), but not a pop-up window of it, so can't understand what's wrong. After debugger usage, realized that the error comes from the destructor. So i'm getting the result "August" but the program don't stop working after that. Assume that the problem is in releasing memory. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class B_class {
    char *p;
public:
    void put_author(char *p) {
        this->p = new char[strlen(p)];
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(p) + 1; i++)
            *(this->p + i) = *(p + i);          
    }
    void show_author() {
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(p) + 1; i++)
            cout << *(p + i);
        cout << endl;
    }
    ~B_class() {
        if (*p) {
            delete[] p;
            p = nullptr;
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    B_class B;
    B.put_author("August");
    B.show_author();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `this->p = new char[strlen(p)];` - you allocated `strlen(p)` characters, but you write `strlen(p) + 1` characters to the buffer.

Comment: Just use a std::string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> this->p = new char[strlen(p)];
> ```

You've allocated `strlen(p)` characters.

> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < strlen(p) + 1; i++)
>     *(this->p + i) = *(p + i);
> ```

You write `strlen(p) + 1` characters into the array. That's one more than the length of the allocated array. The behaviour of accessing an array outside of its bound is undefined.

You can fix this by allocating sufficiently large buffer.

---

If you created an instance of `B_class`, but never call `put_author`, you'd be calling `delete[] p` on an uninitialized pointer. The behaviour would be undefined.

You can fix this by initializing the `p` member in a constructor. Either to `nullptr`, or some buffer allocated using `new[]`.

---

```
if (*p) {
    delete[] p;
```

You only delete `p` if it isn't an empty string. So, if you did `B.put_author("");`, the memory would leak.

You can fix this by removing the `if`.

---

You happen to not do this in your example, but if you made any copies of `B_class` instances, the destructors of those instances would attempt to delete the same buffer, which would result in undefined behaviour.

You can fix this by following the rule of zero / three / five. The conventional approach would be to use `std::string` and get rid of your destructor.